# Is the PIL.being continued for Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using the PIL for Python 2.7 currently, for a school project (an auto-firing IR-guided tracker sentry :P). I'm using the PIL to analyze images and point out the warmest spot (to a limit, of course so that it won't just fire at the sun or closest lamp :P ) and automatically turn towards it and shoot :D. But now I wonder if PIL has been discontinued because it was some time ago that the 1.1.7 release came out for Python 2.7. I'm migrating to Python 3 soon and I'd love to be able to use PIL with it.

Comment: It's not available just yet, but it's being worked on here: https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow. Apparently the first release should be coming within the next couple of months.

Comment: Why are you migrating to Python 3?

Comment: I just feel like it. Knowing both 2 and 3 can come in handy sometime, who knows?